# Problem with php array function displaying only the first item in the array ignoring the rest

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a function to display client's items in an array, however only the first item id is shown in the array. What's wrong with my code? I guess I'm doing something wrong with the array.

Example of `sItem` value: https://pastebin.pl/view/e492ffa1

```
    $items = array();
    $client_item = bin2hex($u->sItem);
    $x = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 78; $i++) {
        $item = hexdec(reverse(substr($client_item, $x, 8)));

        if ($item != 0) {
            $ii = $db->get_object("SELECT * FROM Clients.dbo.ITEM WHERE Num =" . $item);
            if (is_object($ii)) { 
               $items[] = array("ItemID" => $ii->Num, "ItemSlot" => $i);
            }
        }
        $x += 16;
    }
```

The code above will show just the first item in the array. All others are not shown.

```
var items = [{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":0}]
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I remove `$x += 16;` then it will simply add more entries in the array with the first item id. I want more entries but not with the same item id obviously. :)

```
 var items = [{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":0},{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":1},{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":2},{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":3},{"ItemID":310511133,"ItemSlot":4}....
```

This is the `reverse` function:

```
function reverse($str)
{
    $len = strlen($str);
    $i = $len - 2;
    $ret = NULL;
    while (0 <= $i) {
        $ret .= substr($str, $i, 2);
        $i -= 2;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: can you provide values of $u->sItem and $ii

Comment: can you send `reverse` function code as well.

Comment: @NitinGoyal - Yup! I added it in the OP above.

Answer (score 0):

Database Query not returning any object `SELECT * FROM Clients.dbo.ITEM WHERE Num = $item`

can you confirm values exists in database

you can echo $item value and see manually in database are those values exists.

Comment: @Korla can you commenct `$ii = $db->get_object("SELECT * FROM Clients.dbo.ITEM WHERE Num =" . $item);` and just echo `$item` there and validate some of items with database are they exists there or not.
https://pastebin.com/XVY0iYhF